# How can I disable the click event after the div is clicked in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Currently I have two divs render and on click, it checks to see if the answer is correct and increments the questionNumber and correctAnswers. I used setTimeout so there is a delay before rendering the next set of questions.  Problem is, I can click it multiple times before it renders the next problem and it will increment.

I tried using removeAttr and also added the attribute disabled = true. None of these work.  Originally, if the div clicked is the correct answer, i add the class correct and the background will turn blue and red if incorrect.  Ever since I added the attribute disabled = true, it wont even do this and I still can click on it multiple times.

This is the live link to get a better idea.
https://elated-mestorf-900b15.netlify.com/

and this is the github link if its easier to test it out.
https://github.com/davyoon/about-me-react

I have these files in different folders and am importing them.  I separated each file with _____________.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Questions from './components/questions.js';
import QuizBox from './components/quizBox.js';
import Answers from './components/answers.js';


class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    questionNumber: 1,
    correctAnswers: 0,
    isButtonDisabled: false
  };


  onAnswerCheck = (props,e) => {
    let correctAnswers = this.state.correctAnswers;

    if(props.answer){
      e.target.className === "choice-box" ? e.target.classList.add("correct") : e.target.parentElement.classList.add("correct");
      correctAnswers += 1;
    }else{
       e.target.className === "choice-box" ? e.target.classList.add("wrong") : e.target.parentElement.classList.add("wrong");
    }

   this.setState({
      isButtonDisabled: true
    })


    // _________________Add Selected Answer to Database___________________

    let questionIndex = Questions.reduce((target, question, idx) => {
      if(question.number === this.state.questionNumber){
        return target = idx;
      }else{
        return target;
      }
    },0);
    Questions[questionIndex].selected = props.text;

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {questionNumber: prevState.questionNumber + 1, correctAnswers: correctAnswers, isButtonDisabled: false}
      });
    }, 1500)
  };


  render(){

    let content;

    if(this.state.questionNumber < Questions.length + 1){
       content = <QuizBox handler={this.onAnswerCheck} data={Questions[this.state.questionNumber - 1]} questionNumber={this.state.questionNumber} totalQuestions={Questions.length} isButtonDisabled={this.state.isButtonDisabled}/>;

    } else { 
      content = <Answers correct={this.state.correctAnswers} questions={Questions}/>     
    }
    let item = document.getElementsByClassName('choice-box')

    if(item.length > 0){
      item[0].classList.remove("correct", "wrong");
      item[1].classList.remove("correct", "wrong");
    }


    return content;
  } 
}


export default App;


_____________________________________________________________________________


import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './quizBox.css';
import Choice from './choiceBox.js';



const QuizBox = (props) => {

  return(
        <Container className="main-container">
          <Row>
            <h2 className="test">{props.questionNumber} / {props.totalQuestions}</h2>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <p className="question">{props.data.question}</p>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            {props.data.choices.map((choice, idx) => {
              return  (
                <Col md="6" key={choice.key}>
                  <Choice handler={props.handler} text={choice.text} img={props.data.choices[idx].img} answer={choice.answer} number={props.data.number} isButtonDisabled={props.isButtonDisabled} />
                </Col>
              )  
            })}
          </Row>
        </Container>
  )
}


export default QuizBox;

_____________________________________________________________________________


import React from 'react';
import './choiceBox.css';


const Choice = (props) => {

  return(
    <div className="choice-box" onClick={props.handler.bind(this, {answer: props.answer, text: props.text, number: props.number})} disabled={props.isButtonDisabled}>
      <img src={props.img} alt="not loaded"/>
      <p>{props.text}</p>
     </div>
  )
}


export default Choice;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `onClick` fires even though `disabled` is set to `true`, is because divs to not handle `disabled` state the same way `<button>` would.

With this in mind; In your onClick handler, you can have it check if it should render the next question or not.

```
onAnswerCheck = (props,e) => {
    if(this.state.isButtonDisabled){
        // Perhaps throw a UI error?  However you want to handle clicking the div when it should be disabled
    } else {
    let correctAnswers = this.state.correctAnswers;
    ... 
    }
```

Here is an example: https://jsbin.com/gatecatoji/1/edit?html,console,output

Try clicking on button vs clicking the div.